# Annotations on file classes

Tags: annotations, kotlin, static-methods

In my current code (Java), I'm doing some custom annotation processing using class-level Java annotations i.e. the annotations are `@java.lang.annotation.Target({ElementType.TYPE})`.

The target classes contain only static utility methods, so I used file-scoped functions in Kotlin. How do I add these annotations to the generated `Kt` class?

In Java:

```
// Utils.java

package com.example;

@MyCustomAspect
public void Utils {

    public static void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Hello";
    }
}
```

Now in Kotlin:

```
// Utils.kt

package com.example;

// ??? @MyCustomAspect ???

fun doStuff() {
    System.out.println("Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`AnnotationTarget.FILE`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html#annotation-use-site-targets) to allow for Kotlin defined annotation to target the `Kt` class generated from a `.kt` file. Java defined annotation with target `ElementType.TYPE` can also be used to target Kotlin file class:

```
@file:MyCustomAspect

package org.example

@Target(AnnotationTarget.FILE)
annotation class MyCustomAspect

fun doStuff(){

}
```

Comment: I see what you mean. Unfortunately the annotation only has a  `@Target({ElementType.TYPE})`. I cannot change the annotation as it is owned by a separate team.

Comment: @metacubed You can still use it `@file:MyCustomAspect` if the annotation is defined in Java with `@Target({ElementType.TYPE})`